# How to call a second window in powershell and write to it

Tags: powershell

What I am trying to do is run a .ps1 script and while it is executing, it opens a new powershell window and writes certain text to it.

Opening a new window is simple. Among the many ways to do it, I chose `start Powershell`. However, the problem that I am having is that when I type `write-host "ipsum lorem"` it writes it into the native window.

I figured I may have to call the second powershell window and hold that in a variable or object and then write to said variable or object. Every time I try to search in Google, the only results are how to write output and it doesn't talk about running scripts in the native window and writing to a different window altogether.

I understand that `write-host` writes to the native window but I couldn't find anything through `man write-*`/`get-help write-*` or through Google searches.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this and let me know where I might begin to look?

---

Here is an example:

```
start powershell

if($var -eq $sum) {
    # I want this to be written to the second window
    write-host "This condition was met."
} else {
    # I want this to be written to the second window
    write-host "This condition was not met."
}
```

I know that `write-host` shouldn't be used as this writes to the native window but I was just putting it there as a placeholder. Bear with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of opening a second window and trying to write to it from the first? For most use cases this (interprocess communication) is most probably to wrong way to go about it

Comment: It's to separate what is actually running and what I want the user to see. It helps print status info and custom error messages. Makes it simple to troubleshoot with unskilled users. There's more reasons but I just want to print to a second window.

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this (without rebuilding tcl/tk for Powershell) would be to write to a file, then use a different window/editor to display that file with continuous updates (a la `tail -f`). No special technology required for that. Plus it gives you logging for free!

Comment: @PaulHicks That is exactly what I was thinking. I was trying to minimize the footprint but writing to a separate file seemed like the best option. I just wanted to ask and see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned by Paul Hicks in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531508/how-to-call-a-second-window-in-powershell-and-write-to-it#comment62557847_37531508), you could write the output to a file from the first window and read it back in the second window:

```
# Create a temporary file
$tmpFilePath  = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

# Start a new powershell process that tails the temp file
$outputWindow = Start-Process powershell "-NoExit -Command cls;Get-Content $tmpFilePath -Wait" -PassThru

1..5 |ForEach-Object {
    # Do some work and write the output to the temp file
    'Doing step {0}' -f $_ |Out-File $tmpFilePath -Append
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (1..3|Get-Random)
}
Write-Warning 'Please close the other window to continue!'
# You could also use a timeout $outputWindow.WaitForExit(1000) 
# or $outputWindow.Kill() 
$outputWindow.WaitForExit()

# Clean up
Remove-Item $tmpFilePath
```

Comment: Just a quick question: will [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() give the same information as $env:TEMP?

Comment: No, it creates an empty temp file on disk and returns the file path